# Magit: Can offer cursor commit?

Tags: helm, magit

Here my git log:

[image: Git log]

As you can see on top window the cursor is over commit "**settings**". And when I enter command:

```
magit-reset-soft
```

I wait that **Magit** will offer me the next candidate:

`Soft reset to :` **settings**

But it not offer me this options.

Is it possible in Magit?

Comment: If you need more help, ask for it on your other issue, which is about basically the same thing.

Comment: Please add the above screenshot there and add the `helm` tag.